# Преобразование звука

Tags: преобразование, аудио, c++, linux

Как известно в линукс есть консольные прогарммы aplay и arecord
чтобы проиграть звук с микрофона на колонки нужно ввести:

```
arecord | aplay
```

но я хочу добавить эффект дисторшн в эту конструкцию, чтобы было примерно так:

```
arecord | distort | aplay
```

Чтобы можно было например на вход подключить электрогитару ну или просто побаловаться.
Так вот мой вопрос вот в чем: Что мне нужно почитать и что изучить, чтобы я мог написать этот самый distortion?

Comment: это вообще вопрос не по теме форума, на самом деле вам нужно понять JACK - все нормальные аудиопроги для музыкантов через него работают, в jack вы можете просто подключить аппаратный вход к фильтру, эквалайзеру еще чему нить и выдать это на стандарный вывод. Нужно помнить, что jack несовместим с pulse, используйте либо вторую аудиокарту, либо избавляйтесь от pulse (кто вообще придумал на десктопы его ставить, это какой-то заговор по дискредитации аудио в linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вообще для начала нужно прочитать руководство по командам `arecord` и `aplay`. Из него мы узнаем, что по умолчанию они используют формат WAVE. Остается только понять сам формат данных и можно писать утилиту.

Также стоит упомянуть, что нужно научиться работать со стандартным вводом и выводом. Но это должно быть достаточно просто.

Comment: Это я и так понимаю(про стандартный ввод-вывод). Спасибо большое, за желание помочь. я уже написал ее позавчера за 40 минут. все оказалось проще чем я думал.  
всего навсего прочитать где начинается содержимое файла и оттуда начинать пересчитывать.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c, i;
  for ( i = 0; i <= 245; i++)
  {
    c = getchar();
    printf("%c", c);
  }
  while (c != EOF)
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (c <= 198)
       printf("%c", 198);
    else if (c >= 205)
       printf("%c", 205);
    else
       printf("%c", c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

это код, который получился у меня. просто сконвертировать файл можно таким образом:

```
./dist < file1.wav > file2.wav
```